# Django search bar problems

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement a search bar to my website, it's not working and I can't seem to figure out why. The search form looks like this:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}">

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>

    </form>
```

url.py:

```
 url(r'^search/$', views.SearchView, name='search'),
```

views.py:

```
def SearchView(request):

products = Photos.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    products = products.filter( Q(category__contains=query) ).distinct()
    return render(request, 'urcle/search.html', {'products': products})
else:
    return render(request, 'urcle/search.html', {'products': products})
```

search.html:

```
{% extends 'urcle/base.html'%}

{%block content%}

{% if products %}

<div id="inner" >
{% for item in products  %}

<div id = 'content' align="center" ></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2" style="width:30%" >
                <div class="thumbnail" align="left" >
                    <a href="{{item.name}}">                                                         
                        <img src="http://ec2-54-194-123-114.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/images/{{ item.name }}.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>

                    <div class="caption" >
                        <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a>  </li>          
                        <br/>

                    </div>
                </div>





            </div>
            {% cycle '' '' '' '' '' '<div class="clearfix visible-lg">        </div>' %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}

   <h1>nothing to see here!!!</h1>

{% endif %}

{%endblock%}
```

What's really bugging me is that all that gets displayed is the part that gets extended from base.html not even the tag on the else statement gets displayed, anyone know whats up?

Comment: Check if base.html contains {% block content %}{% endblock %}.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a conflicting URL, which was taking me to the wrong view function